# Update data.table based on multiple columns and conditions

Tags: r, data.table

This is a follow-up-question from [Efficient way to subset data.table based on value in any of selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931660/efficient-way-to-subset-data-table-based-on-value-in-any-of-selected-columns).

**sample data**
I have got a data.table with 5 p-columns, indicating a type (type1 or type2 or `NA`).
I also have got 5 r-columns, indicating a score (1-10, or `NA`).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
v  <- c( "type1", "type2", NA_character_ )
v2 <- c( 1:10, rep( NA_integer_, 10 ) )
DT <- data.table( id = 1:100,
                  p1 = sample(v, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  p2 = sample(v, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  p3 = sample(v, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  p4 = sample(v, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  p5 = sample(v, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  r1 = sample(v2, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  r2 = sample(v2, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  r3 = sample(v2, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  r4 = sample(v2, 100, replace = TRUE ),
                  r5 = sample(v2, 100, replace = TRUE ))
```

**desired output**
I want to create two new columns (one for type1 and one for type2) where I check rowwise if type1/type2 has occured in one or more of the p-columns, and if at least one of the corresponding r-column (p1 -> check r1, p2 -> check r2, etc.) contains a value.

**'manual' solution**
This can be done like below, using a lot of AND and OR statements:

```
manual_solution <- DT[ ( p1 == "type1" & !is.na( r1 ) ) |
                         ( p2 == "type1" & !is.na( r2 ) ) |
                         ( p3 == "type1" & !is.na( r3 ) ) |
                         ( p4 == "type1" & !is.na( r4 ) ) |
                         ( p5 == "type1" & !is.na( r5 ) ), 
                       type1_present := "yes"]
manual_solution <- DT[ ( p1 == "type2" & !is.na( r1 ) ) |
                         ( p2 == "type2" & !is.na( r2 ) ) |
                         ( p3 == "type2" & !is.na( r3 ) ) |
                         ( p4 == "type2" & !is.na( r4 ) ) |
                         ( p5 == "type2" & !is.na( r5 ) ), 
                       type2_present := "yes"]
manual_solution[ is.na( type1_present ), type1_present := "no" ]
manual_solution[ is.na( type2_present ), type2_present := "no" ]
```

**Question: automation for dozens of p and r-columns**
But looking at the answers from [Efficient way to subset data.table based on value in any of selected columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931660/efficient-way-to-subset-data-table-based-on-value-in-any-of-selected-columns), I'm convinced there are better ways. Especially since my production data contains A LOT more p-columns and r-columns.

So I started playing around, but got stuck pretty fast...

```
#build vectors p-columns and r-columns
p_cols <- grep( "^p", names( DT ), value = TRUE )
r_cols <- grep( "^r", names( DT ), value = TRUE )

#create logical vectors to test for NA
logi_p <- as.data.table( sapply( DT[, ..p_cols ], function(x) !is.na(x) ) )
logi_r <- as.data.table( sapply( DT[, ..r_cols ], function(x) !is.na(x) ) )

#which non-NA p-values also have a non-NA r-value?
logi <- as.data.table( sapply( logi_p * logi_r, as.logical ) )
```

And now I havent't got any inspiration left on how to proceed.
Any ideas/suggestions?

**bonus**
My main focus is on the question above. But my production data also contains a lot more types (in the p-columns)... So a solution that adds a column by type (or can dcast to this result), would 'kill two birds with one stone'.

Comment: I'm sure there are tricks to do this in a wide format, but I tend to think it's easier to work with data in a long format. Something like this seems to work: `d <- melt(DT, id = "id", measure = patterns("^p", "^r"), value.name = c("p", "r"))`; ``d[ , `:=`(t1 = p == "type1" & !is.na(r), t2 = p == "type2" & !is.na(r))]``; `d[ , .(type1_present = c("no", "yes")[any(t1, na.rm = TRUE) + 1], type2_present = c("no", "yes")[any(t2, na.rm = TRUE) + 1]), by = .(id)]`.

Comment: you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia) useful

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where I convert the type columns into a matrix, update them with information from the `r` columns and then apply over it searching for the relevant type for as many times as there are types to look for.

```
# Convert to a matrix
pMAT <- DT[, as.matrix(.SD), .SDcols = patterns("^p")]
# Subset a matrix with another matrix of the r columns
pMAT[] <- pMAT[DT[, as.logical(as.matrix(.SD)), .SDcols = patterns("^r")]]

types2check <- c("type1", "type2")
for (t in types2check) {
  set(
    x = DT, 
    j = paste0(t, "_present"), 
    value = ifelse(apply(pMAT, 1, function(x) any(x == t, na.rm = TRUE)), "yes", "no")
  )
}
```

**Extra**

Playing with `dcast()` you could do something like the following. Pipes are there just for readability and some of the steps can probably be simplified.

```
result <- data.table(id = DT[["id"]], stack(DT[, ..pcols]), stack(DT[, ..rcols])) %>%
  setnames(c("id", "type", "pind", "rval", "rind")) %>% 
  .[, .(type = type[as.logical(rval)], id)] %>% 
  dcast(id ~ type, value.var = "id", fill = "no", fun.aggregate = function(x) if (length(x)) "yes") %>% 
  .[, `NA` := NULL]

> head(result)
   id type1 type2
1:  1   yes   yes
2:  2   yes    no
3:  3    no   yes
4:  4    no    no
5:  5    no   yes
6:  6   yes    no
```